# Difficulty getting the height of a custom view on cold start

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-density

I'm having some difficulty in getting the height of a view. Currently, upon a cold start of the app, `getMeasuredHeight()` on the view returns `0`.

Now, I know of ways to get around this. It's occurring because the view hasn't been laid out yet. Unfortunately, using something like a `addOnGlobalLayoutListener` won't suffice; I need the height of this view (a toolbar + `TabLayout` or just a toolbar depending on the user's settings) to set the offset for a `SwipeRefreshLayout` using `setProgressCircleOffset()`. Upon a cold start of the app, the `SwipeRefreshLayout` is shown to be "refreshing". Anytime data is loading or changing, it's shown to be " refreshing". If I don't know the height, then the `SwipeRefreshLayout` won't show that it's "refreshing". I can't delay the calculation as I need it at the beginning of a cold start; not to mention it may be one of two possible heights.

So my question is this: since we can get the DPI of a device, and I can generally estimate (by trial and error) the height (in `dp`) of the view (and it's alternate)--is it possible to create a "formula" or something that will adapt the offset based on screen size? I know I'd need to convert the `dp` to `px`, but beyond that, I'm unsure of how to go about this.

For example, I know the height of this view is 334px on my Nexus 6 (set to 513dpi); but it's definitely less on my stock Pixel C (the offset of 334px is too much on a Pixel C).

Comment: Percentage based values will work but I'm not sure why you would want to do this?

Comment: @AMAN77 Why wouldn't I?

Comment: @AMAN77 Would I just do a set percentage of the total screen height? That doesn't seem like a bad option.

Comment: I haven't tried it in Android but it worked out fine in a Apple app I worked on. You should be able to write a very simple function for the height and separately for the width which returns the calcs. But my point was just that its not considered an ideal solution and there is probably a better way to solve your issue. That being said if no one else comes up with something brilliant then go for it or at least it gives you something to try in the mean time.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. I'll definitely give it a try. :) No idea why this didn't occur to me sooner.

Comment: want to submit your comment as an answer? This is what's working; I see no reason to do anything else. Tested on multiple devices and all is good now. :)

Comment: No you were on the right track in your question already. It would be better articulated if you wrote your own answer and in fact if you posted some of the code would be quite an interesting read as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up solving this thanks to AMAN77.

I got the height of the device display (total height in pixels) then multiplied that by a percentage (that I got by trial and error) for the offset.

Here is what I did:

```
    int screenHeight = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    int headerOffset = Math.round((float) (screenHeight * 0.13));

    //if the user has the "toolbar" setting enabled, we need a different offset
    if (SettingValues.single) {
        headerOffset = Math.round((float) (screenHeight * 0.07));
    }

    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setProgressViewOffset(false,
            headerOffset - Reddit.pxToDp(42, getContext()),
            headerOffset + Reddit.pxToDp(42, getContext()));
```

Worked like a charm!